# Backend fine - No dynamic data output to site…

Tags: dynamic

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas or has seen this happen before. I have a site running 1.6.8 (I know very very old now) and it has been running fine for a long time now.

The site has had to be moved to a new server as it (the server) has been massively slowing down as of late and so the host moved everything across to the new server for us.

Upon doing so there is no dynamic data being output to the main site. All template data is being spat out so ExpressionEngine is definitely doing most of its thing and also the admin section is absolutely fine and shows all that it should and works fine it's just that on the main site pages nothing dynamic shows at all.

The caches have been completely deleted by deleting the cache folder from the admin folder but still no dice.

The site is now running a later version of PHP 5.4.37 and I know that EE 1.6.8 isn't supported that far up but I know that people are running 1.6.8 on versions of PHP even higher than that so was just wondering if anyone knows of anything simple that this might be?

Perhaps some PHP config variable or something or another?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Best wishes,

Mark

Comment: Hmm!! :-( Seems that disabling extensions gets the site working again and seems that it's Playa 1.3.1 which isn't working on the site. Does anyone know why that might not work and if there's an update for 1.6.8 at all or any way around this maybe? Thanks.

Comment: A couple quick thoughts ... the PHP version could be something ... I know officially EE that old was never tested on that newer version.  The other thought is that a module / plugin that the site is dependent on is failing in the new version of PHP.  I'd be really nervous having such old software running on newer server software - you're bound to run into weird issues like this.

Comment: Yep it's the 1.3.1 Playa extension which isn't working. Well I say not working as it works fine on the backend and all is great there but if it's enabled then the frontend will not output any data from anywhere, weblogs or anything. As soon as the extension is disabled then all is fine. Looks like I may need to convert that extension to something else and deal with the data but absolutely no idea how to do that. Probably just a line or two or something in the extension file that isn't working well with the PHP version but that's a bit over my head unfortunately :-(